# Convolution properties gives unequal expressions

Tags: fourier-analysis, convolution

Consider the derivative of:
$$I(x)x*I(x)x^3$$
Where $I(x)$ is the indicator function on $[-1,1]$.

One way to evaluate it gives
$I(x)*I(x)x^3$ and the other way gives $3I(x)x* I(x)x^2$ but these two expressions are not equal. Here I am using the convolution property $(f*g)' = f'*g$ and commutativity of the convolution operator.

I'm struggling to see how the $2$ answers can be equal. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Have you tried actually working out both convolutions? For $|x| \ge 2$, it is easy to see that both are $0$. Between $0$ and $2$ each is a 4th degree polynomial. Between $-2$ and $0$, each is a different 4th degree polynomial. Have you worked out what those four polynomials are, to be sure they are not the same?

Comment: I have, they are distinct. I'm not sure what it could be.